# Cannot convert .wav file to .txt file using pocketsphinx

Tags: ffmpeg, mate

I'm new to to this Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu mate:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   Xenial
```

Previously I had normal Ubuntu and I had installed ffmpeg and pocketsphinx for the conversion of mp3 files to .wav files and .wav files to text form. Before upgrading it to Ubuntu mate I was able to do that by using following codes:

1)For .mp3 to .wav

```
ffmpeg -i /home/praveentalavar/Desktop/index/audio.mp3 -ar 16000 -ac 1 /home/praveentalavar/Desktop/index/wave.wav
```

2)For .wav to .txt

```
 pocketsphinx_continuous -infile /home/praveentalavar/Desktop/index/wave.wav -hmm en_US/hub4wsj_sc_8k -lm en_US/hub4.5000.DMP>/home/praveentalavar/Desktop/index/first.txt
```

These codes were working fine before. Now I'm facing the problem. I'm getting the error:

> ERROR: "acmod.c", line 83: Folder 'en-us/hub4wsj_sc_8k' does not
>   contain acoustic model definition 'mdef'

I have tried searching for the solutions and I did not find any proper solution.

Comment: `wav` to `txt`? I have to ask - what would be the output and purpose?

Comment: I,m working on indexing and retrieval of audio books. where i am converting the audio files into text files so that i can search the audio by words . which is necessary for my retrieval part.

Comment: @Cerin Ah, sorry - forgot.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed the version correctly.Try reinstalling with 'mdef' in the correct folder. This is a common problem.